# Login page filter problems

Tags: jsp, servlets, servlet-filters

I'm trying to apply a filter to my login page. I'm just not sure how it works, since I'm not too familiar with filters. I'm trying to redirect a user that logs in to different pages based on their user type. A user has either the user type 'Customer', 'Owner' or 'Mechanic'.
The jsp pages for each usertype are in different directories, which is the problem. 
If I need to supply any code, please tell me. Does anyone know a way I can do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In web.xml you can make entry which will accept a URL-mapping and whenever you will call that URL your filter will intercept that and you can navigate your request to any page.

Comment: Would that mean I'd need 3 filters or can you have multiple URL-mappings in one servlet? I need it to check the usertype and redirect them to the correct page

Comment: If you can use request parameter den you will need one to identify who is logging in otherwise you can also make decision on the basis of URL also if for all type of user its different.